# Would extracting hard-coded subtitles like this work?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, ocr

I have an mp4 with hardcoded subtitles and I want to make an SRT file.

I tried using the video OCR software AviSub. It got the timings right but the words itself were very innacurate, so I got an SRT file that looks like this:

```
1
00:01:22,277 --> 00:01:27,271
innacurate text
innacurate text
2
00:01:38,501 --> 00:01:41,668
innacurate text
```

Now that I have the timings, I want to:

1. Use ffmpeg to extract a frame from each of those timings (I don't know how to do this).
2. Batch OCR all those frames with an accurate OCR software like Readiris (each frame into a separate txt file).
3. Use a Python script to replace the subtitles in the old SRT file with the correct ones from each new text file that was created.

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to decide which frame's OCR'd txt file to use for a given timing in the old SRT file?

Answer (score 0):

You can Extract frames by using this command.

`ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -vframes 1 -ss 00:01:06 outfile.png  -vframes 1 -ss 00:10:30 outfile2.png ...`